# error in acessing Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

while executing the java code to create a node in neo4j we are getting these errors and even we are getting EmbeddedGraphDatabase deprecated.
Can any one give a solution to this??

code:

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine;
import org.neo4j.kernel.*;

public class check{
private static String DB_PATH="/home/ctsf/Documents/neo4j/data/graph.db";

public static void main(String args[]){


    GraphDatabaseService graphdb=new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(DB_PATH, null, null,   null, null);
    ExecutionEngine engine=new ExecutionEngine(graphdb);
    try(Transaction tx=graphdb.beginTx()){
        System.out.println("Entered try block");
        String query= "create (check: see{name:'abc'}) return check.name";
        engine.execute(query);
        System.out.println("exiting....");
    }
    finally{
        graphdb.shutdown();
    }
}
}
```

and errors that we are getting after execution are:

```
 org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.appendStoreDir(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:294)

 org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.<init>(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:270)

 org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:65)
```

Comment: That's just a couple of lines out of the middle of the stack trace. Did you read the Javadoc for the deprecated elements?

Comment: No I didnot. what is the alternative for this graph instantion? "GraphDatabaseService graphdb=new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(DB_PATH, null, null,   null, null);"

Comment: Instatiate your db with `new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);`